# mongodb update document takes document level lock or collection level lock?

Tags: mongodb, locking, insert-update

If in an application, multiple threads are updating documents in mongodb, then mongo db takes document level lock or collection level lock ?

Comment: There is a good topic about your question.
[Mongo locking](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/)

Comment: Good article on lock-level & sharding [link](http://www.arborian.com/2016/03/11/mongodb-mmapv1-wiredtiger-and-queues/)